# web socket is not able to read the cookie produced by http with nodejs in Safari

Tags: node.js, http, cookies

I have the following code that generate cookie in http and later I want the cookie is able to be read by websocket ([ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws))

The issue is when I open the page by **localhost**, the cookie is able to be produced by http nodejs controller and ws is able to access the cookie.

However, when I open the http via **IP address** such as 192.168.0.3, I can see the cookie is generated by http but ws is not able to read it. I have inspected the request header of ws and cookie is not included.
The above scenario works fine on Chrome browser but does not work on Safari 13.0.3

At the following is the code where I produce http cookie (I use [koa2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa2))

```
ctx.cookies.set('token', token, {
    httpOnly: false,
    expires: expiryDate,
})
```

At the following is how I read cookie in nodejs

```
let cookies = new Cookies(req, null);
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers)); //The header does not contain cookie in Safari 13.0.3 with IP address but in Chrome I can see the header has cookie
let token = cookies.get('token');
console.log('Cookie token is: ' + token);  //token value is undefined
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you using the exact same URL for both the http request where the cookie is created and the webSocket connect?  Please show the code for both of those.

Comment: yes exactly the same URL. The code has the following logic: 1. controller produce cookie and pass back in response where open html page 2. html page has javascript that calls ws backend that is located in the same folder as controller. 3. ws read the cookie in th request that is passed in by html javascript.

Comment: Safari is known for not sending `httpOnly` cookies with webSocket connections, but it looks like you're not meaning to set `httpOnly`.  But, perhaps something to verify.

Answer (score 0):

OK the cause is discovered that when I call ws from html page's javascript I assigned the ws server's address as localhost and that is why when ws server receives request it cannot read the cookie set by http which is an IP address